# request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem when uploading a new laravel 5.5 project. When I alter the htaccess in the public_html folder on my server it keeps redirecting. However this problem wasnt there on laravel 5.0. Here's my htaccess from the public_html folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's the htaccess in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

   # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you publish your laravel app to shared hosting?

Comment: Yes, that's why i need the first htaccess file in the public_html

Comment: Try change `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` on your `public_html/public/.htaccess` file to `RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]`

Comment: Nevermind, no new error, just doesnt work .

Comment: Good :D. It's quite risky any way to put all your Laravel codes in `public_html` directory. Someone can see your .env file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that it is really not good idea to put a Laravel project in your Document Root, you have a problem with your htaccess file in your Root directory.
Additional I would at least protect all files in your root folder from direct access:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Fake 404 for all files in /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+$ - [R=404,L]

    # Protect rewrite loop: exclude /public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?public(/.*)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```